# C++ Call Member Function Within An Object of an Object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop, object, pointer-to-member

I have a C++ class which, in short, has a declaration which looks like this:

```
class Pico {
  ...
  Document document; // Custom Document class
  ...
}
```

Later I call one of the public member functions of the `Document` class:

```
this->document->enableEditing();
```

However, IntelliSense underlines `this` and notes that "expression must have pointer type". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: are you calling it from within Pico class method?

Comment: Yes, I am...... <- Used dots for the 15 char minimum entry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
this->document.enableEditing();
```

The `Document` member is not a pointer, therefore you need `.` in place of `->`

Answer (score 2):

`document` is not a pointer, so you do not need the `->` operator:

```
this->document.enableEditing();
```

In fact, in this case it isn't even necessary to use `this` explicitly. The following will do:

```
document.enableEditing();
```